# Javax DocumentBuilder produces “double-UTF-8’ed” charset encoding

Tags: java, xml, encoding, character-encoding

I’ve got a Java DOM `Document` which `MyFilter` has rewritten. From logging output I know that the contents of the `Document` are still correct. I am using the following lines to convert `theDocument` to a `List<String>` to pass it back through an interface:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(theDocument), new StreamResult(buffer));
return Arrays.asList(new String(buffer.toByteArray()).split("\r?\n"));
```

The filter is called from this file copying method using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`:

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(source, "UTF-8");
if (filters != null) {
    for (final MyFilter filter : filters) {
        lines = filter.filter(lines);
    }
}
FileUtils.writeLines(destination, "UTF-8", lines);
```

This works perfectly fine on my machine (where I could debug it), but on other machines just running the code, reproducibly any non-ASCII characters get double-UTF-8’ed (e.g., `Größe` becomes `GrÃ¶ÃŸe`). The code is executed within a web app running in Tomcat. I am sure they are differently configured, but what I want is that I get the non-corrupt result on *any* configuration.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: what does `transformer.transform()` do?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I removed one line too much from the minimal example. It’s just the default transformer retrieved from the `TransformerFactory`.

Comment: After reasoning a while about it it seems almost clear that the wrong step must be during XML *reading*. It seems unlogic that a correct `CharSequence` gets converted to “double-UTF-8”; while it seems quite common that some UTF-8 input gets mis-read as `ISO-LATIN-1`. Question is just why the API does not recognize the correct encoding from the XML header.

Comment: Have you fixed this trouble?

Comment: Have you tried to use `UTF-16` xml files instead?

Comment: Not yet, but the question does not reflect the problem. I got the wrong output method. Sorry about that. The lines of the original question are all in use, but for other XML I/Os (which work as expected). I’m really sorry.
I found out that the characters are still ok during the XML processing, so the problem is during save. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `Document` object created you have to read it Content.

After it you have to write it to file using `LSSerializer` interface, which DOM standart provides for this purpose.

By default, the `LSSerializer` produces an XML document without spaces or line
breaks. As a result, the output looks less pretty, but it is actually more suitable for parsing by another program because it is free from unnecessary white space.
If you want white space, you use yet another magic incantation after creating the serializer:

> ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);

Code snippets looks like:

```
private String getContentFromDocument(Document doc) {
    String content;

    DOMImplementation impl = doc.getImplementation();
    DOMImplementationLS implLS = (DOMImplementationLS) impl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");

    LSSerializer ser = implLS.createLSSerializer();
    ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);
    content = ser.writeToString(doc);

    return content;
}
```

And after you have string content you can write it to file, like:

```
public void writeToXmlFile(String xmlContent) {
    File theDir = new File("./output");
    if (!theDir.exists())
        theDir.mkdir();

    String fileName = "./output/" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_"
            + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".xml";

    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))) {
        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            out.write(xmlContent);
            out.write("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot write to file!" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**BTW:**

Have you tried to get `Document` object at a little bit easier, like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();    
Document doc = builder.parse(new File(fileName));
```

You can try this as well. It should be enough for parsing xml file.

Comment: I voted your question up because you really tried hard to help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it: The problem was within the `String(byte[])` constructor which interprets `byte[]` relative to the platform’s default charset. **This should at least have been tagged deprecated.** The transformer obviously produces UTF-8 output independent of the platform. Changing the method like below passes the same charset to both:

```
final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, ENCODING);
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(theDocument), new StreamResult(buffer));
return Arrays.asList(new String(buffer.toByteArray(), ENCODING).split("\r?\n"));
```

To get it working, it does not really matter which encoding, just both should use *the same*. Hovever, it is good to choose some unicode charset as otherwise unmappable characters may get lost. However, the charset will be reflected in the XML declaration, thus when the `List<String>` gets saved later, it is important to save it accordigly.